# onTouch not working?

Tags: android

Why its not going in onTouch method ? I am using Activity that implements onTouchListener and also I have android:onClick = ObjectClick in my xml where ObjectClick handles the click of the view . I am just using onTouch to get x , y but its not going in to ontouch function

```
public class GamePlayActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

     int click_Locn_x=1,click_Locn_y=1;

// onCreate function is also there .....


public void objectClick(View objectClicked)
     {
         Toast msg;
         int [] locationOfViewInScreen=new int[2];

         int Object = objectClicked.getId();
         View img= (View)findViewById(Object);
         img.getLocationOnScreen(locationOfViewInScreen);
         Log.d("Check:","locn of Image" + locationOfViewInScreen[0]+ "  "+ locationOfViewInScreen[1]);

         Log.d("Check:","locn of click" + click_Locn_x + "  "+ click_Locn_y);     

    }


@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Check"," I am in onTouch Event ");
         click_Locn_x = (int)event.getX();
         click_Locn_y = (int)event.getY();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: show where you are add onTouchListener.

Comment: @appserv : I have added android:onClick:"onTouch" in the xml

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `img.setOnTouchListener(this)` in `bjectClick()`

Comment: But then it will be inside onClick its like it will take frist onClick and then onTouch but I want values to do everything in onClick only

Comment: Best place to put it, is onCreate(), you have just to add the listener once

Answer (score 0):

Just manually setOnTouchListener(this). In xml you do not set listener, you just pass method name.